# Back button in navigation bar doesn't appear

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, tableview

I have a tab bar project. When, from the first view, I call a second view with the comand:

```
- (IBAction) button
{
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

The second view contains a table view that doesn't have the "edit mode":

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}
```

but when the second view appears on the top in the bar doesn't appear the "back" button but appears the "edit" button. On the first view, in `viewDidAppear` i have:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                     target:nil
                                     action:nil] autorelease];
}
```

What can I do? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The navigation item actually belongs to the previous view controller so you should put this code on the view controller which you are returning to. This code works pretty well:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem * btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                            target:nil
                                                            action:nil];

    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:btn];
}
```

Comment: but I have this code on the first view. the first view calls the second with the tableview and this is the view with the problem.

Comment: I don't know what is happening in your code, I checked this in my project - works 100% under ios6.1 xcode 4.6

Comment: maybe there's something wrong in the xib file? something to check or set? The second view has a tableview that calls the 'tableviewcell' to populate the cells.

Comment: I recommend you to create test project and test this. It won't take much time